# iOS 10: HTTP connection is not allowed

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, ios10

Trying to connected my swift application to the server in order to get the data, I got this error when I tested the app in the simulator and the device having iOS 10:

subsystem: com.apple.libsqlite3, category: logging, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0

and also this:

App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

I was first thinking that the problem is with the `http://` so I added this to my info.plist:

```
 <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <false/>
       <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
       <dict>
            <key>yourdomain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
       </dict>
```

But It has no effect at all for the iOS 10 (I don't know about the iOS 9 because I didn't tested it).

Note that my application works perfectly with iOS 8. I'm using Xcode 8 and swift 3.

Comment: Did you change "yourdomain.com" into your own domain?

Comment: yes I change it but I have put the whole url. Have I to put only the part after the "http://"?

Comment: Oh yes it works now! Thank you so much I didn't pay attention to that! I was putting the domain with the "http://" it works when I removed it. Thanks! But can you explain me please why does the problem not appears in iOS 8?

Comment: Only the domain, and without 'www.'

Comment: @RoelKoops you saved me! Thanks! Can you please make it as an answer in order that if someone made the same mistake he could read clearly the answer?

Comment: ATS (App Transport Security) was first introduced in iOS 9, that's why you don't have this problem in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace

```
<key>yourdomain.com</key>
```

with your own domain, and without 'http://'